# How to monitor memory usage of each route in Apache Camel

Tags: java, memory, memory-management, apache-camel, jmx

We want to have a dashboard showing near-real-time memory consumption of individual route in Apache Camel.

I looked JMX, there is a general heap usage. But there is no attributes related to memory of a single route.

Maybe write a customized mbeans with "java.lang.instrument.Instrumentation.getObjectSize" to get a size of the route class? I am not sure how to implement that. Or any other approach to get dynamic memory usage of each routes?

Comment: There is also potential memory leak when add/remove route with JMX  enabled in Production.
http://camel.apache.org/memory-leak-when-adding-and-removing-routes-at-runtime.html